# SSRS - Make text bold based on conditional formatting

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I am using a simple expression to make a few values in a field bold:

=IIF(Fields!header.Value="TOTAL GROUP","Bold","Normal")

However, this is not making the value bold. but in fact removing the value and renaming the rest to Normal. I am not expecting to see this. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're putting the expression for the FontWeight in the Text Box's Value rather than the Font Weight or Style (depending on where you see it).

I usually use the FontWeight property in the Properties window.

[image]

You can also use the Text Box Properties by right-clicking on the text box and selecting Text Box Properties to get the Properties window.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, you are correct I had put it into the wrong place. However, I have now put it into the right place and it is not doing anything at all now. I cannot seem to share a screen grab in here. I have placed the same expression into the bold fx as per your picture.

Comment: I have worked it out, was my own error. Thank you for your help